# Equivalent for Microsoft.SystemsManagementServer.Automation in SCCM 2007

Tags: automation, deployment, sms

**SMS 2003** contained a great feature for automation via the excellent dll: 
**Microsoft.SystemsManagementServer.Automation.dll**. It allowed automating SMS using intuitive objects, properties and methods such as:

```
SMSProvider.Packages.Create("NewPackage");
```

In **SCCM 2007**, it seems this great dll has been deprecated in favor of more WMI style "dog's breakfast" code:

```
var conn = new WMIConnection(@"\\Server\root\sms\site_a", usr, pass);
var queryResults = conn.ExecuteQuery("SELECT * FROM SMS_Package WHERE 
                                      Name='" + packageName + "'");
foreach (ManagementObject obj in queryResults)
{
    packageID = (string)obj.GetPropertyValue("PackageID");
}
```

I am tempted to write my own skeleton classes around these wmi calls. All that seems needed for basic automation would seem to be: **SccmServer**, **SccmPackage**, **SccmProgram** and **SccmTaskSequence**.

**The question is**: does anyone have wrapper, skeleton classes like this available, or know of any open source projects that I can use or adapt? I hate reinventing the wheel for mundane stuff like this.

Comment: Just for the record, I already found this: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/configmgrsdk/thread/07432f0d-09a6-40fb-be38-32898d6a93e8. The question is if someone has started wrapping the new SCCM2007 calls in better wrapper classes.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite as what you are looking for but have you had a look at using [Powershell and SCCM](http://www.myitforum.com/articles/40/view.asp?id=11651) to take some of the WMI pain away?

You might also want to look at:

- [SCCM and PowerShell - Part 1](http://devinfra-us.blogspot.com/2008/04/sccm-and-powershell-part-1.html)
- [SCCM and PowerShell - Part 2](http://devinfra-us.blogspot.com/2008/04/sccm-and-powershell-part-2.html)

There don't seem to be many Powershell cmdlets yet that provide the same level of functionality as Microsoft.SystemsManagementServer.Automation.dll but I did find [PowerShell Community Extensions for Configuration Manager](http://configmgrcx.codeplex.com/).